# codeigniter : how to show single line from db

Tags: php, codeigniter

hello i just like to know how i can show only one line from db.
i can show with foreach loop but cant show without foreach loop
here is my code:

This controller for view data from model

> ```
>  public function view_main_body() {
>                 $data = array();
>                 $data['main_body_details'] = $this->sa_model->select_main_body();
>                 $data['admin_content'] = $this->load->view('admin/view_page_content', $data, true);
>                 $this->load->view('admin/index', $data);
>             }
> ```

```
    here is the model which show data from database
```

> ```
>     public function select_main_body() {
>             $this->db->select('*');
>             $this->db->from('tbl_main_body');
>             $result_query = $this->db->get();
>             $result = $result_query->result();
>             return $result;
>         }
> ```

```
    here is the welcome controller which show in frontpage
```

> ```
> > public function index()
> >             {
> >                     $data=array();
> >                     $data['menu_details'] = $this->sa_model->select_menu();
> >                     $data['maincontent']=$this->load->view('home_message',$data,true);
> >                     $this->load->view('index',$data);
> >             }
> ```

```
    i can show with foreach loop
```

> ```
> > <?php foreach ($main_body_details as $mb_details) { ?>
> >          <?php echo $mb_details->main_body; ?>
> >      <?php } ?>
> ```

but cant show without foreach loop . when i tried its given error.
I like to know how i can post data without foreach loop which show without error

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you want to show the first result row from db??

Comment: yes i like to show first result.

Answer (score 0):

update this function

```
     public function select_main_body() {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tbl_main_body');
        $result_query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $result_query->row();
        return $result;
    }
```

Now remove foreach just look like

```
<?php echo $main_body_details->main_body; ?>
```

Comment: hi asif thanks. its work.
 i like to know another thing. if i show my second row result how i can ??

Comment: there are two ways first is set limit in query limit 1,2 or return complete array echo from index like $arr_name[0]->a,$arr_name[1]->a.. but limit is best way and make sure u will be accept my answer :)

Comment: hello asif
<?php echo $main_body_details->main_body; ?>
this line showing now my fast row
now i like to show second row. how i can ??

Thanks

Comment: do u want know other logic?

Comment: yes. like i want to show my second row from db.
but this  above code which you give me its showing fast row from db.

Comment: update $this->db->get(); to $this->db->get()->limit(1,2) just for second row

Comment: $this->db->get()->limit(1,2) if i use this i am getting error. :S

Answer (score 0):

in the model use

```
$result = $result_query->row();
return $result;
```

this returns only one row. if u have multiple rows it returns first of them

and in view u can access as

```
$main_body_details->main_body
```

[reference](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)

Comment: Hi there can you tell me how i can show second row result ??
like i want to show my second row from db. but this above code which you give me its showing fast row from db.

Comment: as u can see in the reference page  $result_query()->row(2) gives the second row